# What does the Taylor's Inequality mean?

Tags: taylor-expansion

> **Taylor's Ineqaulity**
>
> If $|f^{(n+1)}(x)|\leq M$ for $|x-a|\leq d$, then the remainder $R_n(x)$ of the Taylor series satisfies the inequality
>
> $$|R_n(x)|\leq \dfrac{M}{(n+1)!}|x-a|^{n+1}\text{ for } |x-a|\leq d$$

I'm trying to understand the theorem. Can someone explain it to me intuitively what does it mean?

Comment: It says that if $f^{(n+1)}$ is $O(1)$ on some interval with constant $M$, then $R_n(x)$ is $O((x-a)^{n+1}/(n+1)!)$ on that interval with constant $M$, meaning that the $n$-th error term is $o((x-a)^n)$, i.e. $R_n(x)/(x-a)^n\to 0$. This means that $R_n(x)$ is small compared to $(x-a)^n$ when $x$ is near $a$, which is quite a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

It's a way of saying how close the Taylor approximation is. It also means that Taylor polynomials are generally very good approximations very near the center of the expansion, but might not be good very far away. In particular, if $|x - a| < 1$, then taking high powers of $|x - a|$ is very very small.

As an aside, you may like a [note](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1520) I wrote for my students about Taylor Series. If you think of Taylor polynomials primarily as a tool to get approximations of functions, then it makes sense to understand how good of an approximation you get. [Error estimates are in section 3 of my note]

Comment: How do I get into the section 3?

Comment: @ZhiJTeoh scroll down to it

Comment: @davidlowryduda - appreciated that note; however, when it comes to the remainder, I don't see any explanation as to why Taylor's Inequality provides a limit on the error? In section 3, just after eqn. 3, it simply says 'this is where it comes from.' I know the formal proof, and see how it follows your presentation, but -- especially after you raised the bar with your cogent visual introduction to Taylor series -- I would've loved to see an equivalently revealing presentation fo the remainder statement. Regardless, thank you for sharing the post!

Answer (score 0):

It is an upper bound on the error of the remainder of Taylor's theorem, which allows you to estimate the error of the approximation.